# Return templated smart pointer from constructor-like calls

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, smart-pointers

I want to write some easy-to-call object initializiation and I would like those objects to be shared_ptr of MyClass.

Just for visualisiation purposes, imagine this class:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass(int number);
  MyClass(wxString path);
}

int main()
{
  //For now, objects are created in c style like this:
  MyClass obj1("C:\\test");
  MyClass * obj2 = new MyClass(5);
}
```

Now I would like to change this with easy to use smart pointer initialization.
My goal is something looking like a constructor call, so that very little has to be changed to update the old call to the new one:

```
Smart_MyClass obj1("C:\\test");
Smart_MyClass obj2(5);
//where Smart_MyClass is std::shared_ptr<MyClass>
```

I could solve this with a function:

```
template<typename T>
inline Smart_MyClass Smart_MyClass_Fct(T t)
{
    return std::make_shared<MyClass>(t);
};

Smart_MyClass obj = Smart_MyClass_Fct(7);
```

How can I translate that into the form I need? I could think of using the operator(), that would require a struct/class and maybe inheritence of my actual class? And maybe casting it back to parent class?
Pretty sure there is something more elegant. ;-)

Comment: At a first glance, I would assume that just packing the smart pointer into your own class and forward your constructor parameters to `std::make_shared` should do the trick already. Default copy/move constructor/assignment should already be fine for the rest.

Comment: Sometimes syntactic hiding of "details" is practical (e.g. having to modify a large code base) but often, it is dangerous. There are situations, where smart pointers are not a "safe and sound" thing to use. ``template <class T> struct List { std::shared_pointer<List<T> > next; T value; //... };`` is such an example for dangerous. Why? Because - if your list is long enough and you start to dstroy a node at the front, its destructor will destruct the next value, which in turn destructs the next next until... Stack Overflow! Yay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something along these lines:

```
template<typename T>
class SharedWrapper
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    SharedWrapper(Args... args) : 
        m_p{std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)}
    { }

    T& operator*() const noexcept { return *m_p; }
    T* operator->() const noexcept { return m_p.operator->(); }
    explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return static_cast<bool>(m_p); }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> m_p;
};
```

This just forwards the arguments of the constructor to the `make_shared` functions and then mirrors the interface of the smart pointer. (Here you might have to add additional forwarding methods as needed.)

With:

```
using Smart_MyClass = SharedWrapper<MyClass>;
```

you should get the desired behavior and can also use this for different classes.

However I don't see any possibility to have `Smart_MyClass` actually be a `std::shared_ptr<MyClass>`. Inheriting from `shared_ptr` is discouraged since it does not have a virtual destructor. This might also limit the usability of this approach.

Is there any reason besides style that makes you want to use this notation?

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I am not sure if I want another class as wrapper just for style purposes. The reason I am looking for an easy looking approach is just, that I need to give this code to some people who were stuck with VS2008 and C style programming until recently. I didn't want to poor all that C++ syntax over them, if I could prepare my class with some c style like typedefs and usings. ;-)

Comment: Especially then I would recommend to be explicit in your use of the "new" features and follow the official guidelines. This means if something goes wrong it is easier to look up and to find a solution than when you use some obscure or non-standard measures to make things look like something they are not.